# Data is not defined but can see data in console.log - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently doing an ajax call to an API that retrieves back data from the endpoint. I am able to successfully call the API. When console logging `data.Results.Data[110].DataValue` I get the result back **22,121** which is what I am expecting. I am now trying to use that data in an high charts graph that I created. But when doing so I am getting stuck on an error stating "data is not defined". How do I access `data` so I can properly use `data.Results.Data[110].DataValue` in my graph?

Here is my code.

```
  /* page preloader */
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: gspUrl,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data.Results.Data[110].DataValue, "test")
    },
    error: function (e) {
        // handle exception
        console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
    }
});
});


//Graph

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'State Information'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1997', '1999', '2001', '2003', '2005', '2007', '2009', '2012', '2014', '2016', '2018'],
        title: {
            text: 'Year'
        },
    },

    yAxis: {
        categories: ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10'],
        title: {
            text: 'Percentage Change (%)'

        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'State',
        data: [data.Results.Data[110].DataValue, 2.9, 3.5, 4.5, 8.4, 1.5, 5.2, 6.5, 3.3, 8.3, 3.9],
        color: '#002F65'

    }, {
        name: 'US',
        color: '#0B7070',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 1.9, 5.2, 7.0, 6.6, 4.2, 5.3, 10]
    }]
    });
```

Im trying to use `data` under the `series` section of the graph. How would I be able to access the data coming from my ajax call in my graph?

Comment: Did you put that graphing code inside the `success` callback, where `data` is in scope?

Comment: The graphing code is in the same js file not not in the success call back. Is this where I need to be doing so?

Comment: i've updated my code to show the scope. What I have is the entirety of my js file

Comment: data is only available in success.... That is how scoping works

Comment: Is there a way to allow data to be available throughout ? or is the best way to create a function where the graph is on the success of the ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to retrieve the data is asynchronous. This means your code does not run in the linear fashion you are most likely expecting.

You need to move the code to draw your chart within your success callback or wrap it in it's own function and call it as shown below:

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: gspUrl,
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
      drawGraph(data.Results.Data[110].DataValue); // Call a function that now wraps your graph call
      console.log(data.Results.Data[110].DataValue, "test")
    },
    error: function (e) {
      // handle exception
      console.log("Error occured while reading resource file: ", e);
    }
  });
});


// Graph
function drawGraph(dataValue) {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'State Information'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['1997', '1999', '2001', '2003', '2005', '2007', '2009', '2012', '2014', '2016', '2018'],
      title: {
        text: 'Year'
      },
    },
    yAxis: {
      categories: ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10'],
      title: {
        text: 'Percentage Change (%)'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'State',
        data: [dataValue, 2.9, 3.5, 4.5, 8.4, 1.5, 5.2, 6.5, 3.3, 8.3, 3.9],
        color: '#002F65'
      },
      {
        name: 'US',
        color: '#0B7070',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 1.9, 5.2, 7.0, 6.6, 4.2, 5.3, 10]
      }
    ]
  });
}
```